# SQL displays results for months - how to display only for current year?

Tags: sql, db2

My SQL expression which works fine displays results for months and it will be OK for this year.But after one year I know it will include results from this year. How to show results only from current year?

```
select case month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
        when 1 then 'January'
        when 2 then 'February'
        when 3 then 'March'
        when 4 then 'April'
        when 5 then 'May'
        when 6 then 'Jun'
        when 7 then 'July'
        when 8 then 'August'
        when 9 then 'September' 
        when 10 then 'October'
        when 11 then 'November'
        when 12 then 'December'
    end as Month, 

    count (case when service='ADSL' then 1 end) as  ADSL,
    count (*) as ALL

from INCIDENT
group by month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a `where`clause to the end:

```
where year(STATUSDATE) = year(current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `where` clause!

And you can use `monthname` to get what you're doing in the case:

```
select MONTHNAME(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)) as Month, 
    count (case when service='ADSL' then 1 end) as  ADSL,
    count (*) as ALL

from INCIDENT
where year(STATUSDATE) = year(current_timestamp)
group by month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
```

---

For more info, check [THIS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html) or [THIS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000872.htm).